# Excel Finding a string

Tags: excel, vba

I want to know how to use the find command to search for the string of the current active cell. I though this would work, but I keep getting the "Invalid Qualifier" Error

```
  Dim yaxis As String
  Dim yaxis2 As Range 
  Yaxis = ActiveCell.Value
  Yaxis2 = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:=Yaxis.Value)
```

Error locates me to  this part *(What:=**Yaxis**.Value*)

How can I use the find command to find the string yaxis Is equal to?

Comment: Why don't you just make yaxis2 = activecell? If you use Find to try and Find the value of activecell, won't it just return that cell? Unless there's a duplicate, but without knowing what your code is trying to do it's hard to figure out what would be best.

Comment: The active cell will be on a different sheet than where I am looking.

Comment: Then this won't work as the ActiveCell is within the ActiveSheet. So if Yaxis is the ActiveCell, then the ActiveSheet will be the one which contains Yaxis.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your use of `Yaxis.Value`. `Yaxis` is a string variable and doesn't have a `Value` property. Instead, just use `Yaxis`. You will also need to use the `Set` keyword when assigning to an object variable. Here's the code:

```
Dim Yaxis As String
Dim Yaxis2 As Range
Yaxis = Workbooks("book_name.xlsx").Worksheets("sheet_name").Selection.Value
Set Yaxis2 = Workbooks("book_name.xlsx").Worksheets("other_sheet_name").Cells.Find(What:=Yaxis)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to search for the value of the active cell on a different sheet, you must specify the sheet you want to search. There can only be one `ActiveCell` and it will be on the `ActiveSheet`.

For example, if `Sheet1` is active and you want to search for the active cell's value on `Sheet2`, use:

```
Dim r As Range
Set r = Sheet2.Cells.Find(ActiveCell.Value)

If Not r Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print "Found active cell's value on Sheet2 at: " & r.Address
End If
```